# Admob android giving error code 0

Tags: android, admob

I have setup ad mob on my android app, followed full tutorial

I added `addtestDevice` and it showed me test ad, but now for production i need to show real ads and removed the `addtestDevice` but now I am getting this error.

Export signed app but still no fix

> 02-04 15:12:53.879: I/Ads(24771): Use
>   AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("E31172B18E054F6A03B7BD138EA6B376") to
>   get test ads on this device.
>
> 02-04 15:12:56.699: W/Ads(24771): There was a problem getting an ad
>   response. ErrorCode: 0 02-04 15:12:56.729: W/Ads(24771): Failed to
>   load ad: 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wait for a few hours and you'll start getting the ads. If it is a newly created ad unit id it will take some time for the servers to replicate it on all instances (also called warming up of ad unit).

If it worked with test device id added it will work fine without the test device ids.

Comment: I have the same problem and I have been waiting for a 9 hours and it is not working. Is there anything that we can do ?

Answer (score -2):

Probably not the solution for everyone, but **don't forget to turn off all kinds of adblockers on your phone or network**.

I had a adblocker DNS configured, took me some time to finally figure that out

This is the error you get when the ad is blocked

Comment: this post was for admob library configuration in android development. not for browser.

Comment: @AliZain I think it's pretty obvious that I meant phones. You have many kinds of Adblockers there, one of which is a DNS. I know this wasn't your specific problem but I'm sure this helps others